# VBA Context Menu

Tags: vba, ms-access, contextmenu

Is it possible to display a context menu in Access when the Form's popup setting is set to true?

I have an application where I am hiding the database window (by using acCmdAppMinimize).  I am then setting my switchboard form's Popup property to true, but this disables its context menu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of Access, 2003 ? Anyway, the database window is definitely not a Form, so your question seems very strange and should be clarified.

Comment: What context menu are you speaking of? Do you want your own on the form or are you looking for the File/Edit from Access?

Comment: Hi,
The database window is hidden using acCmdAppMinimize, my form - say Form1 - appears to be floating as Popup is set to true. This gives the impression that the application has not been developed in Access 2003, and looks altogether more professional.

The context menu is my own custom menu. It works fine when the Form's Popup setting is set to False, but doesn't appear when the setting is set to True. Currently, this leaves me in the situation where there is a trade off between having the backround window hidden, and having a custom context.

Comment: I misread your question initially, I tested my context menus with my forms with `PopUp` as true but they still work.  Could you provide more detail?  Maybe the code where you hide the database window.

Comment: I hide it by placing "DoCmd.RunComDoCmd.RunCommand" during the inital Form Open event. My Error message is Method "ShowPopup" of object "CommandBar" failed

Comment: I don't know what you Main menu form looks like, but I am often using the same concept, and I don't see the point of setting the main menu form's as a popup.   

Why would do you want this ? Can't you just set that property to False ?  
Also, If you want to hide Access, why should that popup have a context menu ? I would say it's better if it doesn't.  
Any way, I rewrote slightly your question, but it is still unclear. Perhaps rewrite it and specify your problem better ?

Comment: I was able to recreate the error but as iDevelop said, you could just leave it as a normal embedded form and make it look good by hiding the tab style forms, closing the application when closing the form & distributing the application as `.accdr`